# How to detect and remove duplicate sentences in a string?

Tags: php, string, substring, repeat

I just got help from all of you in another problem, and I was wondering if this next issue of mine can be solved easily as well.

Basically, due to me being stuck with poorly converted pdf to excel file, i have a lot of duplicate sentences in each cell.

For example:

```
$bad_string = "B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >";

$good_string = goodFunction($bad_String);
//echo 'B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >'
```

How the hell is this possible?
The condition is that the bad string is repeated X amount of times. It never changes, it is just like copy and pasted in place many times (due to bad pdf to exel conversion)

Is there ANY solution for this?

Comment: Use **preg_match()** and **preg_replace()** function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `preg_replace`. I assume that the duplicated strings are in continuous form.

```
$bad_string = "B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >";
echo preg_replace('~^(.*?)\1+$~', '\1', $bad_string);
```

Output:

```
B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wX9jU3/2)

If the sentences must end with an `>` symbol, then you could use this regex.

```
(.*?>)(?=(?:.*?\1)+$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wX9jU3/3)

```
$bad_string = "foo B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 > bar B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >";
echo preg_replace('~(.*?>)(?=(?:.*?\1)+$)~', '', $bad_string);
```

Output:

```
foo  bar B7R, B9R, B12R, B12M 430mm Disc 2005 >
```

Comment: your code work very well. But for some reason it fails at this point:
str = "  Centroliner, Cityliner, Linienbus,
  Skyliner, Starliner, Transliner 2 Axles
  continuous potentiometer  Centroliner, Cityliner, Linienbus,
  Skyliner, Starliner, Transliner 2 Axles
  continuous potentiometer
";

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/wX9jU3/4 . With anchors, it fails because it has an extra trailing space. See https://regex101.com/r/wX9jU3/5

Comment: FIXED!! Just removed new lines, that's all.